# How to filter item from a menu

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT

I'm trying to make a user interface that show a menu and a input text.

The menu contains items on tree levels as you can see it in the "Category" menu [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#picktree_combobox_category).
The input text that can filter on the downest item in the menu.

If I put "2" in input text then only Menu with a "2" in the title appear. Parent that have no child dissappear.

Run the snippet to see a quick example of what I want to do.

```js
function mainmenu() {
  $(" #nav ul ").css({
    display: "none"
  }); // Opera Fix
  $(" #nav li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({
      visibility: "visible",
      display: "none"
    }).show(400);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({
      visibility: "hidden"
    });
  });
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  mainmenu();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.nav,
.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 12em;
  top: 1.5em;
}
.nav li ul a {
  width: 12em;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.nav ul ul {
  top: auto;
}
.nav li ul ul {
  left: 12em;
  margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
}
.nav li:hover ul ul,
.nav li:hover ul ul ul,
.nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav li:hover ul,
.nav li li:hover ul,
.nav li li li:hover ul,
.nav li li li li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Quick representation of the menu :</p>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1.2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1.3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3.2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4.1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<input value="" />

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1.2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1.3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3.2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<input value="2" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is this possible with SmartGwt ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to reach to a very similar result. An approach would be to utilize a mix of [Toolstrip](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/toolbar/ToolStrip.html) for the menu, [ToolStripButton](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html) or [ToolStripMenuButton](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/toolbar/ToolStripMenuButton.html), for the sub menus. Also use a [DynamicForm](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html) and a [TextItem](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html) for the input text. When the value of the TextItem is modified intercept the ChangedEvent through the addChangedHandler method and update the menu accordingly.